# How do I refresh my app every second with data from JSON?

Tags: php, android, json, handler, android-volley

I've built an app that gets information from a JSON URL and puts this inside a textview and a BarChart(mikephil's API), but I want it to refresh every second.
Here is my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grafiek);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        Log.d("STATE", savedInstanceState.toString());
    }

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try{

                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                        for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                            String agv = jsonObject.getString("agv");
                            String binnenschip = jsonObject.getString("binnenschip");
                            String vrachtwagen = jsonObject.getString("vrachtwagen");
                            String zeeschip = jsonObject.getString("zeeschip");
                            String opslag = jsonObject.getString("opslag");
                            String trein = jsonObject.getString("trein");
                            String diversen = jsonObject.getString("diversen");

                            agvz = Integer.parseInt(agv);
                            binns = Integer.parseInt(binnenschip);
                            vracht = Integer.parseInt(vrachtwagen);
                            zschip = Integer.parseInt(zeeschip);
                            opsl = Integer.parseInt(opslag);
                            trei = Integer.parseInt(trein);
                            divers = Integer.parseInt(diversen);

                            ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(agvz, 0));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(binns, 1));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(vracht, 2));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(zschip, 3));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(opsl, 4));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(trei, 5));
                            entries.add(new BarEntry(divers, 6));
                            BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Aantal containers");

                            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
                            labels.add("AGV");
                            labels.add("Binnenschip");
                            labels.add("Vrachtwagen");
                            labels.add("Zeeschip");
                            labels.add("Opslag");
                            labels.add("Trein");
                            labels.add("Diversen");


                            chart = new BarChart(mContext);

                            setContentView(chart);

                            BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
                            chart.setData(data);

                            chart.setDescription("");

                            dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

                            /*if(counter == 0) {
                                chart.animateY(2500);
                                counter++;
                            }*/


                        }

                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley","Error");

                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jor);
```

Here is my xml that goes along with it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grafiek"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/parseJsongraph"
    android:text="get DATA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/json"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and lastly: this is where I start my activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    final Button grafiek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grafiek);
    final Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);

    grafiek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            grafiek.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            new CountDownTimer(1000, 50) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    grafiek.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }.start();
            goToGrafiek();

        }

    });
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            info.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            new CountDownTimer(1000, 50) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    info.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }.start();
            goToInfo();

        }

    });
}
private void goToGrafiek() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, grafiek.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void goToInfo(){
    Intent intents = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intents);
}
```

}

Comment: use gcm to update data

Comment: I think you can use handler for that

Comment: set  cronjob from php (web server side) and run your code every second and it will update your data in application(mobile side)

Comment: Why do you need to refresh it every second? It doesn't sound very good in terms of performances imho. What about adding a 'pull to refresh'?

Comment: set timer and call the service at certain intervals.

Comment: I'm not sure if "pull to refresh" works with a barchart. i'll look into the timer though, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Use a handler with timer, create Asynctask every few seconds to get data from Json and add update your layout instead of reloading your activity every time you look for data from server ...

Answer (score 0):

Handler autoUpdateHandler;

**Add this inside your OnCreateView**

```
autoUpdateHandler= new Handler
```

This will call your udpateChartFromJson()  every 1 second.

```
autoUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //start the following method every 1 second. 
                  updateChartFromJson(); 
                  autoUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);

            }
        },1000);
```

From this data will be updated in background as Volley handles its Network call as an Asynchronous Task.

**This like a normal method Declaration:**

```
 public void  updateChartFromJson()
    {
    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try{ 

                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                                String agv = jsonObject.getString("agv");
                                String binnenschip = jsonObject.getString("binnenschip");
                                String vrachtwagen = jsonObject.getString("vrachtwagen");
                                String zeeschip = jsonObject.getString("zeeschip");
                                String opslag = jsonObject.getString("opslag");
                                String trein = jsonObject.getString("trein");
                                String diversen = jsonObject.getString("diversen");

                                agvz = Integer.parseInt(agv);
                                binns = Integer.parseInt(binnenschip);
                                vracht = Integer.parseInt(vrachtwagen);
                                zschip = Integer.parseInt(zeeschip);
                                opsl = Integer.parseInt(opslag);
                                trei = Integer.parseInt(trein);
                                divers = Integer.parseInt(diversen);

                                ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(agvz, 0));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(binns, 1));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(vracht, 2));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(zschip, 3));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(opsl, 4));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(trei, 5));
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(divers, 6));
                                BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Aantal containers");

                                ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
                                labels.add("AGV");
                                labels.add("Binnenschip");
                                labels.add("Vrachtwagen");
                                labels.add("Zeeschip");
                                labels.add("Opslag");
                                labels.add("Trein");
                                labels.add("Diversen");


                                chart = new BarChart(mContext); 

                                setContentView(chart);

                                BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
                                chart.setData(data);

                                chart.setDescription(""); 

                                dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

                                /*if(counter == 0) { 
                                    chart.animateY(2500); 
                                    counter++; 
                                }*/ 


                            } 

                        } 
                        catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley","Error");

                    } 
                } 
        ); 
        requestQueue.add(jor);

    }
```

Comment: so i should put Handler autoUpdateHandler; under my public class MainActivity? if so, where should i put the postDelayed function?

Comment: include the postDelayed function inside your mainactivity onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
        homeCategoriesModalList.clear(); // Clean The List Before Adding Updated Data
        categoryCityAreaRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        jsonResponse();
        categoryCityAreaRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    });
```

> Working on my project

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes